# Generalized Singular Value Decomposition & Sparse Matrices

Tags: math, fortran, implementation, linear-algebra, svd

I want to compute the **Generalized Singular Value Decomposition (GSVD)** for **sparse matrices** A and B. Therefore I am **looking for an implementation** that is capable of using a special data structure for sparse matrices.

The only implementation I found ([here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/db4/dggsvd_8f.html)) is part of the LAPACK package which is written in Fortran 77. 
It works quite good, but unfortunately it can't handle sparse matrices.

Comment: Why not post this on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com?

Comment: "[SVDPACK](http://netlib.org/svdpack/) comprises four numerical (iterative) methods for computing the singular value decomposition (SVD) of large sparse matrices using double precision ANSI Fortran-77." Maybe it helps. I have no experience with this package.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the GENERALIZED singular value decomposition.

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but have you considered writing your own?

Comment: that's what I first tried to do. but I still don't understand the algorithm, my major problem.

Comment: There is a discussion of several different sparse svd pacakges here (in the context of python wrapping, but that doesn't matter): http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/12/19/sparse-svds-in-python/. Also, if you don't mind an extra matrix inversion, you can convert a generalised SVD problem into a regular SVD problem. Of course, this only works if you know that one of your matrices is definitely non-singular.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB's [`gsvd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gsvd.html) accepts [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html). I believe Octave (freely available) supports `gsvd` as well.

Comment: To accept sparse matrices simply means to convert them to full storage and to compute _all_ singular values. The problem here is to have a generalized SV decomposition with the same semantics of `svds` which return just a few singular values, not all.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on Scicomp and got good answers. The post can be found [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/generalized-singular-value-decomposition-only-compute-the-r-largest-singular-va).